# Should events that are no longer needed be unbound?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-events

I have a navigation in my webpage. The navigation shows on clicking a button. Then I close the navigation when user clicks anywhere outside the navigation.

```
$("#navbutton").click(function(){
     if($("#navigation:visible"))
       $('#navigation').hide();
     else {
       $('#navigation').show();
     }
});

$(document).click(function(event) { 
    if(!$(event.target).closest('#navigation').length) {        
            $('#navigation').hide();        
    }        
})
```

Now here even if the navigation is already hidden the click event on `document` will keep firing. I have many other click events on document too.

My question is should removing click event on document when the navigation is already hidden be of any advantage? Would there be some memory of browser released? Would my webpage behave faster? I know the effect would be minor for one event. But, suppose I have 100s of similar navigation. Would removing 100s of those unnecessary events be beneficial?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After reading the title "You Don't Know JS: Async & Performance" getify just stated very clear that pre-mature optimization is the root of all evil.

You can jump directly of that [chapter](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/async%20%26%20performance/ch6.md) of his book.

If this is a simple web page, and there are a moderated amount of DOM objects than having event listeners all the time in the memory will do no harm, and if optimized will offer nothing much of performance.

Before you go into optimization, you have to do some benchmarks and you have to understand what are you benchmarking, and comparing to the real world what do those benchmarking results mean ?

Comment: Would removing `scroll`and `window.resize` event be of any advantage?

Comment: @user31782 this depends as well, but generally yes. Scroll and resize are fired way more often than other events so if you have anything heavy there than remove them. There is also a practice of throttling resize and scroll.

Comment: Do you mean this throttle event https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/  They are executing scrll event after each 100ms? Can we add 100ms in jquery on event like they did?

Comment: @user31782 yes something similar to that

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the elements instead of hiding it, if you don't need it in future, the browser now-a-days removes those event handlers themselves which is one of the way to remove memory leaks.
Recently I went through this blog:

http://javascript.crockford.com/memory/leak.html

This is really helpful blog.

Comment: Would removing `scroll`and `window.resize` event be of any advantage?

Answer (score 0):

Stopping and event or not wouldn't give anything in performance, in fact it would be just unnoticed by the user.

That would be helpful if you want your page to run as fast to IE6 or older browsers. But for browsers just more modern than that you won't get anything more.

You can check this very useful article: [The Dangers of Stopping Event Propagation](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/#article-header-id-3)

Comment: Would removing `scroll`and `window.resize` event be of any advantage?